# No tests discovered using cucumber runner

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, cucumber, junit5

I'm getting an error message while running cucumber tests using gradle:

org.junit.platform.suite.engine.NoTestsDiscoveredException: Suite [features.selenium.runner.RunCucumberTest] did not discover any tests

this is my gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version "6.5.0.3"
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
java.targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client
    implementation 'io.appium:java-client:8.5.1'

    //Http client library
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.14'

    //Jackson utility library to parse POJO to JSON
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.2'

    //Selenium Framework Library
    implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '4.11.0'

    //Library for random string generation in TestEventDataInitializer.java
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'

    // Testing frameworks and libraries

    implementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.23.1'
    testImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.23.1'

    // Cucumber
    testImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.10.0"))
    testImplementation(platform("io.cucumber:cucumber-bom:7.13.0"))
    testImplementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-java")
    testImplementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-junit-platform-engine")
    testImplementation("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")



    // Logging libraries
    testImplementation 'org.codehaus.janino:janino:3.1.9'
    implementation 'org.codehaus.janino:janino:3.1.9'

    testImplementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.5'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.5'

    testImplementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.4.5'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.4.5'

    // General purpose libraries
    implementation 'io.vavr:vavr:1.0.0-alpha-4'

    //CSV files handler
    implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:5.7.1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-junit5
    testImplementation 'io.qameta.allure:allure-junit5:2.23.0'

    //RestAssured libs

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest
    testImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured
    testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured:5.3.1'


}
wrapper {
    gradleVersion = "8.0"
}
test {
    reports {
        junitXml.destination = file("$buildDir/junitreports")
    }
    systemProperties = System.properties

    useJUnitPlatform { config ->
        def device = System.getProperty('device', '').toLowerCase()
        def scope = System.getProperty('scope', '').toLowerCase()

        def handleE2ETestsForDevice = { deviceType ->
            switch (deviceType) {
                case 'android':
                    config.excludeTags 'Windows'
                    config.includeTags 'Android'
                    break
                case 'windows':
                    config.excludeTags 'Android'
                    config.includeTags 'Windows'
                    break
                default:
                    println "Warning: Unknown device '${deviceType}' for E2E tests. Running all E2E tests."
                    break
            }
        }
        switch (scope) {
            case 'e2e':
                handleE2ETestsForDevice(device)
                break
            case 'api':
                config.includeTags 'API'
                break
            default:
                println "Warning: Unknown scope '${scope}'. Running all tests."
                break
        }
    }
}
```

This is my cucumber runner class

```
package features.selenium.runner;


import org.junit.platform.suite.api.ConfigurationParameter;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeEngines;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasspathResource;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME;
import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME;

@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("features")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "pretty")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "features.selenium.stepdefinition")
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

and this is my test

```
package features.selenium.stepdefinition;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;

public class SimpleTest {

  @When("Test")
  public void passOn() {
    assertThat("test").isEqualTo("test");
    System.out.println("TEST");
  }

  @Then("First simple test with Cucumber")
  public void passMe() {
    assertThat("test").isEqualTo("test");
    System.out.println("TEST");
  }
}
```

I tried to switch some dependencies but still getting same error

Comment: You're using `@SelectClasspathResource("features")`. Is that a directory on your class path or only on your file system?

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje it is a directory on my class path

Comment: Try `@SelectClasspathResource("features/selenium/stepdefinition")` and 
`@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "features.selenium.stepdefinition")`

Comment: @Pawel bit hard to say what exactly the problem is then. But it looks like either you're not discovering any tests, or you are discovering tests, but then filtering them out again by tags. Alternatively there are no features on your class path at all.